# SSRS 2012 #Error on divide (NOT by zero)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

The following code

```
SELECT max(operation.setup_hrs),sum(lt2.hours_worked),(sum(lt2.hours_worked)/max(operation.setup_hrs)) ....
```

returns (in the query designer)
0.180     0.46    2.555555

What I'm after, naturally, is

```
max(operation.setup_hrs)/sum(lt2.hours_worked)
```

That, with exactly the same rest of code, returns #Error

As does, since I was trying to catch it being daft with divide again,

```
1/(sum(lt2.hours_worked)/max(operation.setup_hrs))
```

If I manually write (again in the same query, always just replacing that third column)

```
(0.180/0.46)
```

I get the expected 0.391304.  So obviously it can handle the division.

Just for the record, though the results here show that there is no zero involved and still #Error appears, still, I did in my original code (before I started hunting for the bug) have code to deal with eventual zero occurances

```
SELECT iif(sum(lt2.hours_worked)=0,0,
         operation.setup_hrs/iif(sum(lt2.hours_worked)=0,1,sum(lt2.hours_worked)))
```

I'm at a loss: what could be causing the #Error?

Comment: please, add the engine in TAG; mysql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert it to int/double/float etc to do division

```
max(CDbl(Fields!lt2.hours_worked.Value))/sum(CDbl(lt2.hours_worked))
```

Comment: wow; yup, thank you.
`SELECT cast(max(operation.setup_hrs) as float)/cast(sum(lt2.hours_worked) as float) 
worked.
I'm missing *why* that was necessary, though.  The two numbers were both float to start and they were willing to divide the other way to give the float 2.555.  What rule forces this to be cast?  Because now I have to wonder about other divides I have.

Comment: it's better to convert them in SSRS studio to do any calculation, because ssrs studio usually assume those value from datasource as STRING, so .. . #Error
more conversion details refer to : SSRS => Expression => Category => Common Functions => Conversion